# Which primitives does ConTeXt rename/move?

Tags: context, context-mkiv, primitives, context-mkii

TeX's primitives can be renamed by macro formats/packages: this allows new/altered features or behaviours. Usually this is done such that the originals are still available ('renamed'): certainly [LaTeX2e does this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171873) (for example `\@@end`). Which primitives does ConTeXT rename/move, and where do they 'end up'? As there are two ConTeXt versions (MkII and MkIV), are there any differences between the two in this regard?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ConTeXt moves several primitives, renaming them systematically using the prefix `\normal...`. For ConTeXt MkII, all but one of the primitives moved are from TeX90: there is also one from e-TeX and one 'pdfTeX' one that appears only in LuaTeX:

- `\end`
- `\everyjob`
- `\expanded`
- `\input`
- `\language`
- `\mathop`
- `\month`
- `\outer`
- `\over`
- `\unexpanded`
- `\vcenter`

All of these are saved as `\normal...`, *e.g.* `\normalend` is the `\end` primitive.

ConTeXt MkIV moves all of the above plus a few additional primitives from TeX90/e-TeX:

- `\/` (saved as `\normalitaliccorrection`)
- `\hoffset`
- `\left`
- `\middle`
- `\right`
- `\voffset`

MkIV uses some Lua code to extend/alter the behaviour of these primitives: again the originals are saved as `\normal...`.

It also moves two LuaTeX primitives:

- `\bodydir`
- `\pagedir`

These are 'hidden' as `\spac_directions_normal_body_dir` and `\spac_directions_normal_page_dir`: the `\normal...` commands do exist but are not equivalent to the primitives.

Comment: @JosephWright: There are unofficial public git repos of the ConTeXt betas at http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/shortlog/refs/heads/origin and https://gitorious.org/context. Running [git blame](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blame/088de88944c1f2254250bb448c7371a87ff7ee39:/tex/context/base/math-fen.mkiv) on math-fen.mkiv shows that these primitives were overridden on `2013.10.20` commit: http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/commit/b8ac6d7b7fdb16293c28034c349efd5b0b7b20b3?f=tex/context/base/math-fen.mkiv

Comment: @Aditya Thanks: that what I suspect, but wanted someone with a bit more knowledge to help me out :-)

Comment: It seems as if `\mathop` is *not* moved in current TL2016 MkIV.  If I typeset the following minimal expample `\starttext\meaning\mathop\stoptext` it simply prints `\mathop`.

Comment: Furthermore is `\outer` is just empty macro.

Comment: @HenriMenke Reuse (or similar) is a different question: if you want the `\outer` primitive in ConTeXt then `\normalouter` (or `\primitive\outer` or a Lua approach) is the way to go.