# Which primitives does LaTeX2e rename/move?

Tags: latex-base, primitives

TeX's primitives can be renamed by macro formats/packages: this allows new/altered features or behaviours. Usually this is done such that the originals are still available ('renamed'): certainly [ConTeXt does this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171800/which-primitives-does-context-rename-move) (for example `\normalend`). Which primitives does the LaTeX2e kernel move/rename?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The LaTeX kernel (`latex.ltx`) saves a few primitives with new names: these are all from TeX90 as the kernel itself does not absolutely require primitives from e-TeX or later. Two of these are token registers, saved as `\frozen@...`:

- `\everydisplay` saved as `\frozen@everydisplay`
- `\everymath` saved as `\frozen@everymath`

The other 'renamed' primitives are all saved as `\@@...`:

- `\-` saved as `\@@hyph`
- `\/` saved as `\@@italiccorr`
- `\end` saved as `\@@end`
- `\input` saved as `\@@input`
- `\par` saved as `\@@par` (note that `\par` is still the primitive in the preamble)
- `\underline` saved as `\@@underline`
- `\shipout` saved as `\@@shipout` (but used by the kernel as simply `\shipout`: the saved primitive is to allow for packages that need to get to
  the raw behaviour irrespective of other loaded material)